# How to analyze the performance of a Java Class without actually running it?

Tags: java, performance, static, analysis

We need to implement an application for evaluating results of an online programming challenge. The users will implement the programming challenge and compile their source through a web interface. We are supposed to compile the submitted sources on the fly and present some statistics of the program like expected memory consumption and possible performance indicators of the sources. Does anybody know how can we gather memory consumption and performance indicators of the program statically from the sources?

Comment: you won't be able to find everything unless you want to solve the halting problem but I believe there are static code profilers out there...

Comment: Even if you run the application it can be hard to measure how much CPU and memory it required.  Even for trivial examples, it is hard to determine this statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something very useful. I am not sure if this is what I am looking for. I am yet to analyse the results. But this is quite interesting. 
We can gather some performance statistics using the HPROF profiler agent shipped with the JDK release. The good thing is that it can be run during the compilation to produce some interesting statistics on the code beign compiled. Following are some samples. More details can be found at http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/tooldescr.html#gbluz

```
$ javac -J-agentlib:hprof=heap=sites Hello.java
SITES BEGIN (ordered by live bytes) Wed Oct 4 13:13:42 2006
          percent          live          alloc'ed  stack class
 rank   self  accum     bytes objs     bytes  objs trace name
    1 44.13% 44.13%   1117360 13967  1117360 13967 301926 java.util.zip.ZipEntry
    2  8.83% 52.95%    223472 13967   223472 13967 301927 com.sun.tools.javac.util.List
    3  5.18% 58.13%    131088    1    131088     1 300996 byte[]
    4  5.18% 63.31%    131088    1    131088     1 300995 com.sun.tools.javac.util.Name[]

$ javac -J-agentlib:hprof=heap=dump Hello.java
HEAP DUMP BEGIN (39793 objects, 2628264 bytes) Wed Oct 4 13:54:03 2006
ROOT 50000114 (kind=<thread>, id=200002, trace=300000)
ROOT 50000006 (kind=<JNI global ref>, id=8, trace=300000)
ROOT 50008c6f (kind=<Java stack>, thread=200000, frame=5)
:
CLS 50000006 (name=java.lang.annotation.Annotation, trace=300000)
    loader        90000001
OBJ 50000114 (sz=96, trace=300001, class=java.lang.Thread@50000106)
    name        50000116
    group        50008c6c
    contextClassLoader    50008c53
    inheritedAccessControlContext    50008c79
    blockerLock    50000115
OBJ 50008c6c (sz=48, trace=300000, class=java.lang.ThreadGroup@50000068)
    name        50008c7d
    threads    50008c7c
    groups        50008c7b
ARR 50008c6f (sz=16, trace=300000, nelems=1, 
     elem type=java.lang.String[]@5000008e)
    [0]        500007a5
CLS 5000008e (name=java.lang.String[], trace=300000)
    super        50000012
    loader        90000001
:
HEAP DUMP END


$ javac -J-agentlib:hprof=cpu=times Hello.java
CPU TIME (ms) BEGIN (total = 2082665289) Wed oct 4 13:43:42 2006
rank   self  accum   count trace method
   1  3.70%  3.70%       1 311243 com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile
   2  3.64%  7.34%       1 311242 com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile
   3  3.64% 10.97%       1 311241 com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile
   4  3.11% 14.08%       1 311173 com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile
   5  2.54% 16.62%       8 306183 com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.listAll
   6  2.53% 19.15%      36 306182 com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.list
   7  2.03% 21.18%       1 307195 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main
   8  2.03% 23.21%       1 307194 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete
   9  1.68% 24.90%       1 306392 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter
  10  1.68% 26.58%       1 306388 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter
...
CPU TIME (ms) END
```

Answer (score 2):

While you could possibly do static analysis of the source to infer performance characteristics, I suspect it would be far simpler to just run a JUnit test suite over the code.

If you can present your challenge as a code stub or interface, you should be able to create a suitable JUnit suite which validates correctness and tests performance.

Granted, JUnit may not be the best way of running performance tests but you can likely bend it to the task. Alternatively you could look at [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) or something similar.

Comment: If you run the code, make sure that you sandbox the JVM properly to handle malicious submissions.

Comment: Indeed. Ideally it would be run in a separate JVM with a suitable security policy in place.